# MariaDB 10.0.17 group commit replication speed

Tags: mysql, amazon-ec2, parallel-processing, replication, mariadb

I am running a MariaDB 10.0.17 master/slave pair with non-gtid async replication setup trying to achieve higher replication throughput than the single threaded replication by using the group commit.

I am using r3.4xl, EBS optimised with a 900GB LVM XFS 4k IOPS EBS PIOPS volume.

On my workload with single threaded replication I get a maximum of 3.4k WPS of replication speed.

With the settings below I get 8k WPS of replication speed, but it is not sustained. Both master and slave when taking only write traffic and with a 1000/1000 buffer pool hit rate fluctuate between two states:

a) (according to iostat) the EBS volume does ~2k write/s (and 25% util) where the master achieves 10k WPS and the slave achieves 8k WPS

b) (again according to iostat) the EBS volume does ~1k write/s and ~1k read/s (and 50% util) where the master achieves 6.5k WPS and the slave does 4k WPS.

Can anyone shed any light on what could be causing the nodes to fluctuate between those states? each state can last anywhere between a couple of minutes and an hour.

Here's the relevant part of my config

on master:

```
binlog_commit_wait_usec = 20000
binlog_commit_wait_count = 50
```

on slave:

```
slave_parallel_threads = 16
```

and on both

```
innodb_file_per_table = 1
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 2
innodb_log_file_size = 8G
innodb_flush_method = O_DIRECT
innodb_file_format=barracuda
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 92395M
binlog_cache_size = 1M
innodb_buffer_pool_instances = 8
innodb_max_dirty_pages_pct = 80
innodb_io_capacity = 20000
innodb_io_capacity_max = 30000
innodb_write_io_threads = 32
innodb_read_io_threads = 32
innodb_thread_concurrency = 16
innodb_flush_neighbors = 0
```

Comment: Would you care to discuss what the application?  There may be some high-level design change that could let the overall system run significantly faster by not needing so many WPS.